# Toggle blog articles (expand/collapse) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle

in my blog some articles are very long. So I want the long articles to be collapsed when the page is loaded. It works for me for just one article but if I have more articles something seems to be broken.

Here's how I do it:

```
$('div#ttoggle').hide();
$('#btoggle').click( function() {
    if($('div#btoggle p').text() == 'expand article'){
        $('div#btoggle p').text('collapse article');
    }else{
        $('div#btoggle p').text('expand article');              
    }   

    $('div#ttoggle').slideToggle("slow");           
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using an `id` selector for something which you state will appear multiple times on the page. `id` attributes must be unique, so this would be invalid HTML and could be causing this to fail.

The solution here would be to replace all `id`s with `class`es. You can use the `.classname` selector to select the appropriate elements

Answer (score 1):

You are using ids "#btoggle" where you probably want classes.  You should only ever have a single element with a given id.

You are assigning a click handler to a number of elements, but then deciding what to do by examining all the element afresh.  Instead use `this` inside your handler to only consider the clicked element:

```
$('div#ttoggle').hide();
$('#btoggle').click( function() {
    var tog = $(this);
    var togp = tog.find("p");    
    if (togp.text() == 'expand article') {
        togp.text('collapse article');
    }
    else {
        togp.text('expand article');              
    }   

    tog.siblings('div#ttoggle').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

(I don't know what your HTML actually looks like, I took a guess at the siblings.)

Comment: thanks, but I have a "p" element inside the div#btoggle. so I need to set the text of the p element. how do I do that?